# Calling sub with objects

Tags: vba, oop, excel

As a Java and Javascript developer I've some trouble when working with objects and classes (do we use the term `class` in vba?) in [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba). I know that I can pass objects `ByVal` or `ByRef` and that I have to (manually) extend my arrays with `ReDim`.

Concerning my problem: I try to create a list of customers. A customer has an address and a name. Name's a simple `String` and address another class. I iterate through a list of `Cells` and after rediming my array I add a new customer with the following snipplet (`extractAddress` returns an address object):

```
ReDim Preserve customers(i)
Set customers(i) = New Customer
Call customers(i).create(Sheets("Customers").Cells(pos, 1), extractAddress(Val(pos)))
' ^^^ error's here ^^^
```

My customer class' `create` method looks like

```
Public Sub create(name As String, ByRef address As address)
  CustomerName = name
  CustomerAddress = address
End Sub
```

When running this code I get an *Run-Time Error 91: Object Variable or With block not set* Error for the highlighted line. `extractAddress` is successfully returning an object (not `Nothing`). I don't know which object variable isn't set accordingly.

I tried to change my `create` method to only take a name or an address as parameter but both approaches didn't solve my problem. If I comment out the erroneous line my script (obviously) works just fine. So I reason that something's wrong with my `Call`.

Side question: Why is the vba code editor camel-casing Customer when all other of my custom classes are lowercased?

---

Appendix:
`extractAddress` function

```
Private Function extractAddress(row As Integer) As address

  Dim address As New address
  Call address.create(Sheets("Customers").Cells(row, 2), Sheets("Customers").Cells(row, 3), Sheets("Customers").Cells(row, 4), Sheets("Customers").Cells(row, 5))

  Set extractAddress = address

End Function
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `extractAddress` method?

Comment: I appended the requested method

Comment: 1) VBA is NOT case sensitive. 2) passing objects is only ByRef, AFAIK. 3) I can't refrain - sorry - but all cases where I had to work on a VBA app made by "java guys" were a nightmare of unnecessary complexity :-/ good luck !

Comment: @iDevlop: AFAIK ByRef is only the default method for passing objects. According to several websites it's still possible to explicitly pass them ByVal. If anyone can understand it, anyone can replace you ;)

Comment: Have a look at *user defined data types*.  Perhaps that might help you. And frankly, I believe to be quite expert in VBA and I developed on that environment for years, VBA Class modules are VERY rarely necessary/usefull. I don't know java, and I quite a beginner in c#, but normal procedures in VBA are Subs or Functions, and you will get better results if you start by using Excel's built-in objects as much as possible.

Comment: @iDevlop my comment shouldn't be offensive!

Comment: No problem at all, I did not take it that way. Same for mine !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Set` when setting a variable to an object.

So, change this line in the `Customer.create` method

```
CustomerAddress = address
```

to

```
Set CustomerAddress = address
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked and it's so obvious. Don't know why I couldn't solve it myself.

Comment: It's an easy one to miss. I missed it at first too. That's why I asked to see the code for the `extractAddress` method...I was thinking it wasn't returning what you thought it was.